# What's the better way to build a binding form using react / redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I'm new to React-Redux and I'm trying to build a binding-like form using a `Material-ui TextField` and display his content in a div when any changes happened. There is my code:

**TextField Component:**

```
handleHead = event => {
  store.dispatch(newTitle(event.target.value));
}
render() {
return (
    <div>
       <div style={MDStyle}>
            <TextField style={dblock} 
              floatingLabelText='Title' 
              onChange={this.handleHead}
          fullWidth={true}/>
    </div>);
 }
```

**Reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

function markdown(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'NEW_TITLE':
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            title: action.text
          });
        default:
          return state;
    }
} 

export default combineReducers({ markdown });
```

**Store**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers  from '../reducers/Reducers';

const initialState = {
  markdown: {
    title: ''
  }
};

const store = createStore(reducers, initialState);
export default store;
```

The problem comes when I try to type something in the Input, it loses focus and I can't keep typing anything. Seems like the component re-renders. What's the easiest way to solve this? Considering that these kind of problems have been solved before in `react-form` or even `refs`, Can you give me some guidelines or best practices for solving this?

Comment: check [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/)

Comment: I will suggest you to give a value to TextField that you get from redux store. Also try and make use of provider and connect approach rather than subscribing to store

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Please recommend some references of provider and connect approach

Comment: Have a look at this example from redux official documentation http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html